# Finding the expected value of running time with if statement

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

I was working on a problem to find the average case of a for loop that has a 1 step in it. The each element in the input array has a distribution of {0...i} where i is the index of the element.

What threw me off was that, in the for loop there is an if statement that would prematurely end the for loop and this "if statement" would be executed if the value of the array was 50.

The Psuedocode looks somewhat like this:

```
for i from 0 to n-1:
     do something
     if L[i] == 50:
         do something, and break
```

and the input of the array are distributed like this:

```
L[0] = {0}
L[1] = {0, 1}
L[2] = {0, 1, 2}
L[i] = {0, 1, 2, .., i}
```

With duplicates being allowed and they're independent.

---

I already realized that there really was no need to look at the summation before index 50 of the array. Further more, the probability of not getting the value of the array was quite obviously i/i+1, however with this being said I do not know how to fully use the expected value theorem to get the expected running time of the program.

I would just like a little tip to get me on track. I feel like im really close to solving this but yet so far, thank you

Comment: Although the description of the code can be useful, it would be helpful if you would *provide* the (pseudo)code you are referring to.

Comment: Of course @trincot my mistake. I reedited my initial post! Thank you

Comment: Could you also add a sample input array? Are duplicates allowed in the input? What is the connection between 53 and 50 in your question? How could the probability of not getting the value depend on *i*? Should it not depend on *n*?

Comment: @trincot re-edited the question one again sorry it made no sense at first. 
But the reason why the probability of not getting the value 50 was dependent was because L[i] could be i possible values (as seen in the example I gave) so the possibility of getting the number 50 out of i possible values (assuming i>50) wouid be 1/i. Well thats what I found atleast

Comment: It should break at average somewhere around i=100, so in general it should be constant running time. Because the probability of L[i] not being 50 is i/i+1 then the probability that none of L[i],L[i+1],...,L[i+n] is 50 is i/(i+1)*(i+1)/(i+2)*...*(i+n)/(i+n+1)=i/(i+n+1) so putting i=50 and n=49 gives the probability 0.5. So it's as likely to hit a 50 then not to hit it.

Comment: I don't think the answer is a constant running time. On average the code will end 50% before 98 and 50% after 98, *but* in the second case the duration can be very long. For the expected value, the duration for each case has to be multiplied by the corresponding probability, and then the sum needs to be taken. This is a number that keeps increasing for increasing *n*. Somewhere around *O(sqrt(n))*, but that would be more a question for https://math.stackexchange.com/